# how to use CircularFloatingActionMenu in eclipse

Tags: android

im trying to use this library in eclipse but all the tibs to use it is in android studio how except the codeing of course how can i use it in eclipse
https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu

Comment: I'm also using eclipse and when i see the answer here i have tried steps like in answer, but i'm getting so many errors in java files. Did you solved those errors or did you at all got those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to add the "java" folder in to your source files:

- Clone the library
- Import it to Eclipse (File -> Import)
- Go to the library's properties (Right click on the library -> Properties)
- Open Java build path
- Go to Source tab
- Add the "java" folder and then apply your changes

Comment: thanks bro it worked                 anta 3arby  i mean bttklm 3raby